# Cannot resolve symbol 'ActivityRecognition'

Tags: android, google-api-client, activity-recognition

I've tried a whole month to learn to use Google's Activity Recognition service, and met a very confusing problem while adding ActivityRecognition.API to mGoogleApiClient.

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(ActivityRecognition.API)
        .build();
```

I'm given an error which says "Cannot resolve symbol 'ActivityRecognition'". 
Then I imported anything that looks related with ActivityRecognition like,

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.ActivityRecognitionClient
import com.google.android.gms.location.ActivityRecognitionResult
import com.google.android.gms.location.ActivityRecognitionResultCreator
import com.google.android.gms.location.DetectedActivity
```

and nothing worked.
I can't even find a person who encountered this situation. Also, the [official document](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognition) shows ActivityRecognition is not deprecated.

[Here is my screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5zhi.png) (Please ignore the underline of 'this'. That has been solved, and I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with the 'ActivityRecognition' error. )

I'm using Android Studio 1.3.2 on Windows7 x64. I don't know if this information is necessary.

Activity Recognition will surly help a lot on my developing app. Sincerely hope someone could help me.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I've successfully dealt with this problem. I think it's related to the version of Google Play Services.

I replaced my original version of 4.1.32 with a new version of 8.1.0, which I see in a Google's official example. 
If anyone face the same problem, go to gradle(module), in the field of dependencies, update your

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:[version]'`

to a higher version. Hope this will help.